# How do I either find and delete a particular font installed by me or reset my fonts to the default ones?

Tags: fonts

I installed a font called Caribbean Island for some web development, but decided that I didn't like it. I later found out that Chromium was replacing the fonts on some webpages (such as all gawker sites), and it looks very ugly. How do I get rid of this thing?

Things I've tried, but didn't come up with anything relevant:

- Searching the entire system for anything with the words 'caribbean' or 'island'
- Opened synaptic and did a search for 'ttf-'
- `sudo apt-get remove ttf-caribbean-island` with every other combination of dashes and syntax you can think of.

Best case scenario: a way to completely reset all of the fonts.

Any help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Font Manager](http://code.google.com/p/font-manager/) is a simple tool to install/remove individual fonts or collections.

[image: Font Manager screenshot]